# Creating Activity by using AsyncTask in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I'm having an exception when running the following code.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button btnSend, btnDelete;
EditText edtUsername, edtPassword;
TextView tvUsername, tvPassword;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    initializeProperties();

    btnGonder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View view) {           
        login("aaa@bbb.com", "123456");
    }});
    btnSil.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View view) {
        clearView();
    }});
}

private void initializeProperties() {
    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDelete);
    tvUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUsername);
    edtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    tvPassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPassword);
    edtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
}

private static final String readInputStream(java.io.InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    java.io.InputStreamReader streamReader = new java.io.InputStreamReader(stream);
    java.io.BufferedReader bufferedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(streamReader);
    String line, redText = "";
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        redText += line;
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    return redText;
}

private void clearView() {
    edtPassword.setText("");
}

private void login(String username, String password) {

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.1/api/login");

    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);

    //HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        // Add your data
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(
            String.format("{ 'Email': '%s', 'Password': '%s' }", username, password)
        ));
        // Set Headers
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        //response = new AsyncLoginHandler(alertBuilder).execute(httpPost).get();
        new AsyncLoginHandler(alertBuilder).execute(httpPost);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        alertBuilder.setMessage(uee.getMessage());
    }
}

class AsyncLoginHandler extends android.os.AsyncTask<HttpPost, Void, HttpResponse> {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder;

    AsyncLoginHandler(AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder) {
        super();
        this.alertBuilder = alertBuilder;
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpResponse doInBackground(HttpPost... params) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            try {
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(params[i]);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                alertBuilder.setMessage(cpe.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                alertBuilder.setMessage(ioe.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                alertBuilder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return httpResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse response) {
        if (response != null) {
            try {
                java.io.InputStream stream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                String result = readInputStream(stream);
                alertBuilder.setMessage(result);
            } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
                alertBuilder.setMessage(ise.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                alertBuilder.setMessage(ioe.getMessage());
            }
        }

        super.onPostExecute(response);

        alertBuilder.create().show();
    }

}
```

}

Well... The Android's documentation page for [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (please refer to the title "The 4 Steps")states that onPostExecute is invoked on the UI thread; However I'm having the following error after "**alertBuilder.create().show()**;".

```
 - 10-04 06:36:25.607: W/dalvikvm(711): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:517)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at org.gdgankara.com.LoginActivity$AsyncLoginHandler.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:139)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at org.gdgankara.com.LoginActivity$AsyncLoginHandler.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:1)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
 - 10-04 06:36:25.657: E/AndroidRuntime(711):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: a builder takes an activity as context, it doesn't work with getApplicationContext()

Comment: @njzk2 : it worked Thank you! But how? Does that supposed to mean that the UIThread and the application thread differs? why LoginActivity's context is different from LoginActivity.getApplicationContext()?

Comment: Check my post http://stackoverflow.com/a/10346079/598170

Comment: the application and the activity are different things. only the activity context has a hook to a graphical token

Comment: @njzk2: so the Activity's thread and Application's thread are the same, but the Context instances are different? so things are connected with Contexts in Android I guess. Am I right?

Comment: something like that, yes. (even more, there is only one UI/main/system thread for all applications) (which is why you must never block (sleep/wait/networking/any long operation) it)

Answer (score -1):

The doInBackground method cannot touch the view of the main thread. Meaning that you can't set the message of the alert dialog form the doInBackground method. try to remove the set 3 set messages from the catch inside the doInBackground and run the application.

Comment: wrong and irrelevant. setMessage is in an AlertDialog.Builder, which does not need to be accessed on the ui thread, as it does not contain any graphical widgets

Comment: try to create the builder inside onPreExecute

Comment: getting worse. if you `builder.create()` in `onPreExecute`, your builder builds an AlertDialog with the data given to it (probably not much at this point). You are then free to either use this alertDialog (and, indeed, not modify its content outside the ui thread) or fill your builder, and create a complete AlertDialog later.