# How to update listview calling Asynctask to call a webservice

Tags: android

I know that there is this question, but, I can't get that it works to me,  I think it could be a little different, I have a webservice to get the datas, and I have a listView in my activity. I want to update this listview.

I have been trying with a Handler, but, it's not working,, although, I appreciate others options. I don't really know, if I should access directly to the list from my AsyncTask class or how I could update.

UPDATE:
So, I'm not using a nested class to my AsyncTask, it could be easier on this way, but I don't want to do it because I use this class in more places on my code. I'd like knowing how I could access to the activity and load my ListView with my datas what I get from my WS. I guess that it's a bad idea to use a Handler to do it.

My Activity class is:

```
public class GameOnlineListActivity extends Activity {


private static final String TAG = "GameOnlineListActivity";


// List view
private ListView lv;

// Listview Adapter
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

// Search EditText
EditText inputSearch;

// ArrayList for Listview
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

// List with datas
String users[];

// Handler on the main (UI) thread that will receive messages from the 
// second thread and update the progress.
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // Get the current value of the variable total from the message data
        // and update the progress bar.         
        users = msg.getData().getStringArray("users");
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_online_list);
    users = new String[0];
    callWebService();
    // Listview Data

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);



    // Adding items to listview

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, users);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My webservice is a little long code, because I use the same class to call several webservices,,

```
 public class WebServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {


private static final String TAG = "WebServiceTask";

// connection timeout, in milliseconds (waiting to connect)
private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 3000;

// socket timeout, in milliseconds (waiting for data)
private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000;

private int taskType;
private Context context = null;
private Activity activity = null;
private Handler handler;

private String processMessage = "Processing...";

private List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
private ProgressDialog pDlg = null;


public WebServiceTask(int taskType, Activity context, String processMessage, Handler h)     {

    this.taskType = taskType;
    this.activity = context;
    this.context = context;
    this.processMessage = processMessage;
    this.handler = h;

.....

private void handleResponse(String response) {
    try {


   ......

        case ConstantsTrivial.GET_USERS:

            respJSONArray = new JSONArray(response);
            listUsers = new ArrayList<Usuario>();

            for(int i=0; i<respJSONArray.length(); i++)
            {               
                JSONObject obj = respJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);                
                id = obj.getInt(ConstantsTrivial.USER_ID);
                userName = obj.getString(ConstantsTrivial.USER_NAME);
                keyId = obj.getString(ConstantsTrivial.USER_KEY_ID);
                usu = new Usuario(id, userName, keyId);

                listUsers.add(usu);

                String[] names = new String[listUsers.size()];
                int z = 0;                  
                for (Usuario u : listUsers){
                    names[z] = u.getUserName(); 
                    z++;
                }


                Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putStringArray("users", names);            
                msg.setData(b);
                handler.sendMessage(msg);


            }
            Log.d(TAG,"Lista recuperada de Usuarios por webservice:" + listUsers);
            break;
        }

   } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
   }

 }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

    handleResponse(response);

    //pDlg.dismiss();

}
```

I got a solution, but I don't really like it, and I don't want to do it like that... it's really messy.. This code is really dependent of that Activity, I'm looking for something no too much dependent because as I said,, the WebServicesTask is a class that it could call from anywhere. :(

```
  case ConstantsTrivial.GET_USERS:

            respJSONArray = new JSONArray(response);
            listUsers = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
            String[] names = null;

            for(int i=0; i<respJSONArray.length(); i++)
            {               
                JSONObject obj = respJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);                
                id = obj.getInt(ConstantsTrivial.USER_ID);
                userName = obj.getString(ConstantsTrivial.USER_NAME);
                keyId = obj.getString(ConstantsTrivial.USER_KEY_ID);
                usu = new Usuario(id, userName, keyId);

                listUsers.add(usu);

                names = new String[listUsers.size()];
                int z = 0;                  
                for (Usuario u : listUsers){
                    names[z] = u.getUserName(); 
                    z++;
                }


            }
            Log.d(TAG,"Lista recuperada de Usuarios por webservice:" + listUsers);
            //NEW CODE, UPDATE!!!!
            ((GameOnlineListActivity)activity).adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, names);               
            ((GameOnlineListActivity)activity).lv.setAdapter(((GameOnlineListActivity)activity).adapter);
            ((GameOnlineListActivity)activity).adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            break;

        }
```

Comment: What does not work? Where are you trying to update the data in the ListAdatper? Also you should move the code where you parse the data to the doInBackground() method because this might take a while and could block the UI thread. Finally, doInBackground() runs in a separate thread, onPostExecute() in the UI thread, so no Handler is needed there.

Comment: I'm parsing the datas in onPostExecute, if you realize, the parser is in the fuction handleRespose what it's inside of onPostExecute. In my doInBackground what I'm doing it's just the call to the webservice, is it right?

Comment: I'm tryting to update in my Activity through the Handler,, but, really, I just tried this,, but, I don't know really how I'd do it.

Comment: Edited main message with a possible and ugly solution..

Comment: Okay, I got another intermediate solution. I have create an abstract class which extends Activity with a method call updateActivity(Object param), So, all my activities are going to extends this class instance Activity class. I could call this method from my AsyncTask if it's necessary to update some element.

Answer (score 0):

Just google for "android listadapter asynctask". You'll find plenty of examples, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335718/using-asynctask-to-display-data-in-listview) which is very similar to your task.